# constructores en laravel7

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos select en eloquent que se repiten en muchas funciones, de qué forma podría evitarse el estar escribiendo  `$ajustes = Ajustes::All();` `$categorias = Categoria::All();` en todas mis funciones estos dos selects siempre??

intente usar un __construct de esta forma

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $ajustes = Ajustes::All();
        $categorias = Categoria::All();
    }
```

Variables `$ajustes` y `$categorias` se repiten en todas las fuciones dentro de mi contrador

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $ajustes = Ajustes::All();
        $categorias = Categoria::All();
        
        return view('welcome',compact('ajustes','categorias'));
    }
```

Espero explicarme bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Si los inyectas como argumentos del constructor?

Comment: Si los paso como argumentos desde las funciones tendría que inyectarlos?

Comment: Y por qué no los mueves a un trait?

Comment: Supongo que hablas del constructor del controlador. Lamentablemente creo que hace falta un poco más de contexto, pero en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) hay ejemplos básicos para inyectar dependencias. Saludos

Comment: @BetaM trait son como los helpers?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Claro pero lo quiero es no repetir codigo creo que lo mas funcionaria seria lo que dice BetaM

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: @JoséVásquez Entonces quieres declarar esas 2 variable (`$ajustes y $categorias`) para que se utilize en cualquier funcion dentro de tu controlador?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo no realizar operaciones en el constructor porque si usas un metodo que no necesite hacer la carga de datos, lo hará y hará lenta tu aplicación.

Inyecta los modelos y guárdalos en variables de la clase para que los puedas utilizar sólo cuando los necesites.

Dentro de tu clase podrías tener:

```
protected $ajustesModel;

protected $categoriasModel;

public function __construct(Ajustes $ajustes, Categoria $categorias)
{
    $this->ajustesModel = $ajustes;
    $this->categoriasModel = $categorias;
}


public function index(Request $request)
{
    $ajustes = $ajustesModel->all();
    $categorias = $categoriasModel->all();

    return view('welcome',compact('ajustes','categorias'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Variables vs Propiedades de Instancia

El error en tu intento fue que declaraste tus colecciones como si fuesen una variable cualquiera:

```
public function __construct()        {
        $ajustes = Ajustes::All();
        $categorias = Categoria::All();
}
```

Acción que limita su existencia al scope del constructor. Apenas éste se ejecuta la referencia a ellas se pierde y quedan a dispósición del garbage collector como memoria liberable.

(**Edit**: esto en lo que respecta a fast-cgi. Si se usa un gestor como php-pm o roadrunner seguirán en alguna parte del éter hasta reiniciar el proceso)

Para adosar estas colecciones como propiedad de la instancia, esto se asigna con `$this->{nombre}`.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection */
protected $ajustes;

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection */
protected $categorias;

public function __construct()        {
        $this->ajustes = Ajustes::All();
        $this->categorias = Categoria::All();
}
```

Ojo que lo correcto es declarar esas propiedades de instancia con su respectiva visibilidad. Si estás usando PHP 7.4 puedes además declarar su tipo sin tener que recurrir a las anotaciones en docblocks.

(Al dejarlas como `protected` las hago visibles para cualquier controller que herede del actual y no necesite declarar nada distinto en su constructor).

#### Comportamiento de `compact`

Esto nos lleva a un segundo problema, y es que, si bien podrás evitar ejecutar la consulta `{Model}::All` en cada método, tu uso de `compact` asume que hay dos variabes en el scope con nombres `$ajustes` y `$categorias` y te oligará a ponerlas como tal

```
  public function index(Request $request){
        $ajustes = $this->ajustes;
        $categorias = $this->categorias;
        
        return view('welcome',compact('ajustes','categorias'));
    }
```

Puedes modificar eso para darle a la vista un array de variables explícito:

```
 public function index(Request $request){
    return view('welcome', [
       'ajustes' => $this->ajustes,
       'categorias' => $this->categorias
     ]);
 }
```

#### Compartir variables a todas las vistas

Si los otros métodos usan esas mismas variables para sus respectivas vistas, tendrás código repetido:

```
 public function item(Request $request, int $item_id){
    return view('item', [
       'ajustes' => $this->ajustes,
       'categorias' => $this->categorias
       'item_id' => $item_id
     ]);
 }
```

Para este caso sería más limpio compartir esos valores a todas las vistas usando el método `share`  en el facade `View`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class EjemploController extends Controller {

    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection */
    protected $ajustes;

    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection */
    protected $categorias;    

    public function __construct()        {
        $this->ajustes = Ajustes::All();
        $this->categorias = Categoria::All();

        View::share('ajustes', $this->ajustes);
        View::share('categorias', $this->categorias);
    }

    public function item(Request $request, int $idem_id){
      return view('idem_id', [
         'idem_id' => $idem_id 
      ]);
    }
```

El método `EjemploController::item` ahora sólo necesita declarar en la vista sus variables particulares. Las otras dos ya están inyectadas

#### Caché de Colecciones

Como bien dice [@Omar Alvarado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/113238/omar-alvarado), poner la consulta en el constructor implica ejecutarla aunque quieras mostrar una vista que no utiliza esos datos.

Lo correcto sería, en cambio, poner esa operación en el método `handle` de un middleware. En particular, de un middleware que intervenga solamente en el grupo de rutas que utiliza tus variables de selectores.

Pero, siendo bien específicos, para este caso de uso sería incluso mejor aprovechar que parece tratarse de entidades que se modifican muy de vez en cuando, y dejar las colecciones en caché.

Dónde poner ese caché? Para algo tan general se podría poner en el método `boot` de `AppServiceProvider`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $categorias = Cache::remember('categorias', 600, function () {
            return Categoria::all();
        });
        View::share('categorias', $categorias);
    }
}
```

Pero si implementas la idea de manejar todo esto en un middleware, entonces ahí es el lugar óptimo